# How to refer to a param in an aws lambda in ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a ruby lambda with

```
def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
  p "#{event}"
end
```

Test Event is

[image]

It show the event:

```
"{\"param1\"=>\"abcdefg\", \"key2\"=>\"value2\", \"key3\"=>\"value3\"}"
```

but how do I get the param ?

I tried

```
      p "#{event[param1]}"
      p "#{param1}"
```

but neither worked

Error from first:

```
"errorMessage": 
"undefined local variable or method `param1' for #<LambdaHandler:0x00005597b5a7c608>",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works:

```
p event["param1"]
```

or you can also use string interpolation:

```
p "#{event['param1']}"
```

Output from both:

```
"abcdefg"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access it in the lambda, for ex:

```
get_param = lambda { |key, val| key == 'param1'.to_sym }
```

then say

```
param = event.select(&get_param)
p param
```

haven't used aws lambdas in Ruby before but maybe this will help! (Try `to_sym`?)